# VS code has 'ImportError: No module named MyQR '

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used `pip install MyQR` command on Windows and successfully completed installation.

The path is 'C:\Users\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\MyQR'

When I using VS code and `from MyQR import myqr`,it returns 'ImportError: No module named MyQR', I wonder how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install the module "`MyQR`" in your currently selected [conda environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments) (shown in the lower left corner of VSCode), and activate this environment in the console.

(You can use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VSCode terminal, the terminal will automatically enter the currently selected environment and activate it)

[image]

Check the installation package:

[image]

More reference: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).